# JBoss: How to generate a Web Service FROM a WSDL?

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, wsdl, wsdl2java

I need to prototype a very simple system which sends a request to a remote web service, which will then callback on my own web service once it's finished processing. Unfortunately, I have to implement their WSDL for the callback.

Is there a nice simple way of generating a JBoss application which will correctly implement the WSDL, and run some trivial java code?

I tried wsdl2java from Apache CXF, but that only gave me a standalone server, not a deployable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this [tutorial](http://labs.jboss.com/jbossws/docs/jaxws_userguide-2.0/index.html) help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2).